# Know how to change boot order, Have Ubuntu 13.04 on a bootable usb stick, but won't load

Tags: boot, usb

As the title says, I have a bootable usb drive, and Ubuntu 13.04 is installed on it, but when I change the the first boot device to the usb, it doesn't load and goes to windows. Can you help?

Comment: can you test your usb drive on an other computer? to make sure whether the usb-creation went alright. if this works, can you give info on your system, maybe there might be a problem with secure boot or uefi, but I have no experience with those. maybe [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) article will help

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other computers to use, i'm pretty sure I formatted it right though. I have a Dell Inspiron 3520 (Intel i3 at 2.3GHz, 4GB ram, Windows 8)

Comment: in the article I linked ([this one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)) there is mentioned that with windows 8 you need to disable [FastStartup](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: How did you create the USB, and what make and model is your system?

Comment: I have listed the make and model above (Mitch), and thanks for the information on that, I'll try what that article says (Wouter)

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS again, I bet your USB stick is recognized as HDD, so what you have to do is to take a look (in BIOS) at the HDD priority, set your USB stick as first HDD, then change the boot order and making it to boot from HDD first.

Comment: Its recognized as the model name of the usb (sandisk cruzer facet) and ive tried changing the priority, to no avail

Comment: What I mean is that your system could be identifying the USB as HDD and not as a Removable Device, so my advice is (in case this is happening, of course) to select HDD as first boot priority and then check that your first HDD is your Sandisk, once this is done press F10 to save and exit.